# Iframe 4shared invisible chrome and ie9

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, iframe, browser, internet-explorer-9

The following code is not being visible in the browser chrome and IE9 seems not to open or invisible generated by this code and playlist on 4shared

```
<iframe marginWidth=0 marginHeight=0 frameborder=0 border=0 cellspacing=0 src=http://www.4shared.com/pl/Dd1KpM8G/Need_For_Speed_-_The_Run.htmlscrolling=no width=320 height=260></iframe>
```

for test: http://gamermag.com.br/index.php/screenshots-e-wallpapers/

Comment: Did you try to set the values in quotation marks? `<iframe marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" frameborder="0" border="0" cellspacing="0" src="http://www.4shared.com/pl/Dd1KpM8G/Need_For_Speed_-_The_Run.htmlscrolling=no" width="320" height="260"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

As @dop-trois said the values should be in quotes.

```
<iframe marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" frameborder="0" border="0" cellspacing="0" src="http://www.4shared.com/pl/Dd1KpM8G/Need_For_Speed_-_The_Run.html" scrolling="no" width="320" height="260"></iframe>
```

​Remember that some websites prevent loading their pages in iFrames with JS similar to below so if you try loading a site like that (twitter for example) it won't show anything or redirect your whole page to their site. Just be careful of that.

```
if(top.frames.length > 0)
    top.location.href=self.location;
```